# How to remove unused kernels and reclaim disk space inside VM?

Tags: linux-kernel, hyper-v

I am using hyper-v to create a VM running Ubuntu guest. I git cloned the kernel source, and compiled it.
Then second time, I wanted to modify the kernel source. Just the default settings other than adding a custom name to the version.

```
make menuconfig
make
make modules_install
make install
```

When I ran modules_install, I saw an error message that my VM ran out of free space. I managed to allocate more space to the virtual hard drive and solved the issue then.

While booting up, the grub displays 3 different kernels available.
My question is, what is taking up all the disk space?
If i keep compiling kernels, will that take GBs of my disk? If so, how can I free up space? Can I delete the unused kernels to reclaim some space?

Please suggest.

hago

**Update 1**
The output of `ls -l /boot` is

```
total 1319637
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    224422 Aug  1  2019 config-5.0.0-25-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    224535 Jul  6 22:35 config-5.1.0-eudyptula-h.1.1-dirty
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    224525 Jul  2 18:15 config-5.1.0-h.1.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    224538 Jul  1 20:06 config-5.1.1hago_1_1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    224538 Jul  1 19:25 config-5.1.1hago_1_1.old
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root       512 Jan  1  1970 efi
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root      4096 Jul  6 22:43 grub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  40808013 Jul  1 19:18 initrd.img-5.0.0-25-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 410846721 Jul  6 22:41 initrd.img-5.1.0-eudyptula-h.1.1-dirty
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 410821916 Jul  2 18:19 initrd.img-5.1.0-h.1.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  10622869 Jul  1 21:07 initrd.img-5.1.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 410847209 Jul  1 21:09 initrd.img-5.1.1hago_1_1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    182704 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    184380 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    184840 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw------- 1 root root   4290047 Aug  1  2019 System.map-5.0.0-25-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4346940 Jul  6 22:35 System.map-5.1.0-eudyptula-h.1.1-dirty
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4346456 Jul  2 18:15 System.map-5.1.0-h.1.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4346456 Jul  1 20:06 System.map-5.1.1hago_1_1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4346456 Jul  1 19:25 System.map-5.1.1hago_1_1.old
-rw------- 1 root root   8711928 Aug  1  2019 vmlinuz-5.0.0-25-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8808832 Jul  6 22:35 vmlinuz-5.1.0-eudyptula-h.1.1-dirty
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8808832 Jul  2 18:15 vmlinuz-5.1.0-h.1.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8808832 Jul  1 20:06 vmlinuz-5.1.1hago_1_1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8808832 Jul  1 19:25 vmlinuz-5.1.1hago_1_1.old
```

**Update 2**
Now when I boot the VM, I see another new kernel version 5.3.0 appearing in the GRUB menu.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the output of `ls -l /boot` (mount it first, if necessary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since these are custom-built, all you have to do is rm all the old kernels you don't want anymore, and then `sudo grub-mkconfig`. Note that /boot isn't the only location, there are kernel files in /lib/modules/ and /var/lib/initramfs-tools/ as well, although not nearly as large. `apt` won't keep anything you build yourself cleaned up, unfortunately.

Comment: thanks. By rm all the old kernels, you meant to remove them from the  /boot,  /lib/modules/ and /var/lib/initramfs-tools/ dir? and then run sudo update-grub2?

Comment: The update just looks for a vmlinuz and then does some checks to ensure its related files are also present. Removing them and removing the grub entries is painless. I also just found out that grub-mkconfig is the command now, and the older ones are just symlinked to it; all these years and I never noticed.

Comment: Thanks. I found that /lib/modules had few directories taking up GBs of space. I deleted 1 dir related to an unused kernel and reclaimed 5GB of storage.

Answer (score 1):

A typical size for the initrd is in the tens-of-megs range.  Your custom builds are 410MB.  Check your kernel build settings and exclude things from the initrd that can be loaded post-boot.